# LSB replacement and its effect on grayscale histogram

Tags: steganography, image

I used [this](https://github.com/Serux/MATLAB-custom-steganography/blob/master/Matlab_Steganography.m) program to embed some text data in grayscale image, then I compared original and stego histograms in Matlab using imhist function. You can see both on them below: [image: here]

Can somebody explain to me what exactly is going on in the stego histogram? Why are there 2 shades of blue? Is this how I should be comparing such images or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LSB-Steganography you store your bitstream in the least significant bit, thus in the first bit of every pixel. doing so you change rgb-values that should ideally not be recognized by human eyes. The more data you put in it the easier it is to be recognized like your histograms shows.